# How to use $lte with alias?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize select query with an alias and I want to have only the ones where count is lower than 5.

I already have a query, which gives me the count and makes the join correctly. I really only need the part for have the count < 5.

```js
Stock.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('*')),{stockcount: {$lt: 2}}, 'stockcount']],
        group: ['fk_product'],
        include: [{
            model: Product,
            as: 'product',
            attributes: {exclude: ['fk_creator']},
            include: [
                {
                    model: Category,
                    as: 'category'
                },
                {
                    model: User,
                    as: 'creator',
                    attributes: ["id", "username", "jabber", "email"]
                }
            ]
        }],
        where: {sold: 0, replace_unit: null}
```

Currently Im getting a result of this:

```
{
        "stockcount": 8,
        "product": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "First Product",
            "description": "Some Description",
            "product_type": 0,
            "price": 9.99,
            "catId": 1,
            "rating": 0,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-19T22:56:43.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-01-19T22:56:43.000Z",
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "catname": "First category",
                "icon": "fa-user",
                "createdAt": "2019-01-19T22:56:43.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2019-01-19T22:56:43.000Z"
            },
            "creator": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "testt1",
                "jabber": "test@test1.im",
                "email": "test@gun.de"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "stockcount": 1,
        "product": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Second Product",
            "description": "Some Description",
            "product_type": 1,
            "price": 1.99,
            "catId": 1,
            "rating": 2,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-19T22:56:43.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-01-19T22:56:43.000Z",
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "catname": "First category",
                "icon": "fa-user",
                "createdAt": "2019-01-19T22:56:43.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2019-01-19T22:56:43.000Z"
            },
            "creator": {
                "id": 2,
                "username": "username",
                "jabber": "test2@test.im",
                "email": "test@test.de"
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see there is a field "stockcount", which is an alias. My Problem is, Im not getting to use it to use Op.lte: 5 or something like that. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't that sort of logic go into a `having` clause?

Comment: yes you are right I think. I tried having: 'stockcount' < 5, but its not working Im getting the same result as in the startpost. It generates: HAVING 1=1

Comment: Could try `Sequelize.literal('stockcount') < 5`?

Comment: solved it with this: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('*')), '<', 5)